# R: ARIMA model and autocorrelaction between residuals

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, arima, autocorrelation

In the article:
Assessing global COPD awareness with Google Trends
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333155916_Assessing_global_COPD_awareness_with_Google_Trends

I found the following description of the statistical analysis:

*For statistical analysis, we subdivided data into months (seasonal component) and quarters of the year, which were defined as follows: Quarter 1 (Q1) = January – March, Quarter 2 (Q2) = April – June, Quarter 3 (Q3) = July – September, Quarter 4 (Q4) = October – December. 
Correlation analyses were performed using the Seasonal Decomposition of Time Series by Loess (Local Polynomial Regression Fitting), which allows to decompose the time series into seasonal part, trend and irregular components. **A generalized least squares model accounting for autocorrelation between residuals was established to further evaluate whether a trend is significant over time, after adjustment for the seasonal components. The correlation structure of residuals was deduced from an automatic selection of ARIMA-model parameters using AIC criterion**.*

The data was expressed as coefficient (beta), standard error and p-value.

I completely do not understand the bolded fragment. I prepared some code for preparing ARIMA model from a time series data. However, I do not know the autocorrelation calculation process.

Let's see some code:

```
library(forecast)
data(AirPassengers)
model_arima<- auto.arima(y=AirPassengers,seasonal=TRUE,stepwise=TRUE)
model_arima
Series: AirPassengers 
ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,1,0)[12] 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2      ma1
      0.5960  0.2143  -0.9819
s.e.  0.0888  0.0880   0.0292

sigma^2 estimated as 132.3:  log likelihood=-504.92
AIC=1017.85   AICc=1018.17   BIC=1029.35
```

... and how should look the next step to get the autocorrelation results as in the abovementioned article?

Comment: After decomposing the series the authors run an ARIMA on the residuals. Apparently, in your code, `auto.arima` selects the best fit automatically by smallest AIC, which is the method described in the bold text part of the quote in the question.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code with ARIMA on the residuals and the results?

Comment: Start with `d <- decompose(AirPassengers)` then `auto.arima(d$random, seasonal = FALSE)`.

Comment: I run the following code:
`library(forecast)
data(AirPassengers)
d <- decompose(AirPassengers)
a <- auto.arima(d$random, seasonal = FALSE)
library(lmtest)
coeftest(a)

z test of coefficients:

     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
ar1  0.769358   0.085867  8.9599  < 2e-16 ***
ar2 -0.147915   0.110153 -1.3428  0.17933    
ar3 -0.206134   0.111950 -1.8413  0.06558 .  
ar4 -0.020891   0.114832 -0.1819  0.85564    
ar5 -0.149498   0.090668 -1.6489  0.09918 .`

Which "ar" and following coef, se and p-value is that mentioned in the article? The first one?

Comment: That is something you must understand yourself, SO is for questions on code, not statistic analysis.